Select row according to priority in XML content
I have data stored in xml format in my postgresql database. For some records there are several xml but I would like to select only one based on a priority.



publication_id
xml




162382550
{<abstract load-source="patent-office"><p num="0000">Text1</p></ abstract>}


162382550
{<abstract load-source="docdb"><p>Text2</p></abstract>}



I want to select the record where load-source is patent-office. If this source is not available I want to select docdb. Obviously I don't want to select both records at the same time.
I have tried that but obviously it picks the 2 records and they are both present.
select publication_id,  xpath('/abstract', xml.content) as abstract from xml where publication_id = 162382550 and (xpath('abstract/@load-source', xml.content)::text  = '{patent-office}' OR xpath('abstract/@load-source', xml.content)::text  = '{docdb}');


Okay, it works using ORDER BY and LIMIT
select publication_id,  xpath('/abstract', xml.content) as abstract
from xml abs
where publication_id = 162382550 and (xpath('abstract/@load-source', xml.content)::text  = '{patent-office}' OR xpath('abstract/@load-source', xml.content)::text  = '{docdb}')
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN xpath('/abstract/@load-source', xml.content)::text = '{patent-office}' THEN 1
    WHEN xpath('/abstract/@load-source', xml.content)::text = '{docdb}' THEN 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ELSE 3 END
LIMIT 1;

